# Wordpress Underscores, toggling class with mouseup doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, underscores-wp

I'm using Underscores as my base theme for a site, and I really dig that it includes a workable mobile navigation element as a part of the theme. But this is essentially a one-page site, and the navigation doesn't "de"-toggle when a link is clicked... because it's not leaving the page.

So I wrote a little script.

The php-generated-HTML is essentially this (simplified for this post):

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation toggled" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="mobile-menu" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa-bars fa"></i></button>
    <div class="menu-main-nav-container">
         <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="true">
             <li class="menu-item"><a href="LINK">Link 1</a></li>
             <li class="menu-item"><a href="LINK#anchor-on-the-page">Link 2</a></li>
             <li class="menu-item"><a href="LINK#different-anchor-on-the-page">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And here is the script I wrote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.main-navigation.toggled li.menu-item a').mouseup(function(){
        $('.main-navigation.toggled').removeClass('toggled');
        $("button").attr("aria-expanded","false");
        $("#primary-menu").attr("aria-expanded","false");
    });
</script>
```

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm overlooking, but I don't see it.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you expect to happen with your script versus what is actually happening?

Comment: I expect for the class "toggled" to be removed and for the two aria-expanded states to be changed to "closed." Nothing is happening.

Comment: Is your event triggering?  You can place a console.log as the first line in your function to verify.  Also, change` $("button")` to `$('button')` and `$("#primary-menu")` to `$('#primary-menu')` .  When I run your code in [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5rs3jx2/1/) with those changes, toggled class is removed and the aria-expanded attributed are set to false.  Perhaps something else is interfering?

Comment: Tried it to no avail, and when I look at your JS FIddle, doesn't seem like clicking one of those links changes anything...? I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong, but I don't see it.

Comment: Sorted it out... don't know why, but when I just removed `'.main-navigation.toggled'` it did the trick.

Comment: you have to look at your brower's console to see what's happening to the DOM elements in that fiddle I posted.  For example, look at the attributes of the button before and after clicking a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Here's what it was, and I don't know why, but when I removed `'.main-navigation.toggled'` it worked. Doesn't make sense to me because those classes are definitely there, but I also don't care ... because it worked. :)

Thanks for your help, folks!

Comment: For anyone reading this and wondering why that worked, it's because the element doesn't exist on page load, at least not with the 'toggled' class' as that's only added when the menu is opened. Just removing toggled would also work, as would `$(document).on('click', '.main-navigation.toggled, function(){#). The OP's code worked worked me with this modification.

Answer (score 0):

How is your whole page setup? If this javascript isn't running from the footer you may need to wrap your javascript in a document.ready. It might be running when the elements aren't rendered yet and the mouseup event might not get attached.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
    $('.main-navigation.toggled li.menu-item a').mouseup(function(){
        $('.main-navigation.toggled').removeClass('toggled');
        $("button").attr("aria-expanded","false");
        $("#primary-menu").attr("aria-expanded","false");
    });
    });
</script>
```

Here's a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/zsecLnd6/

If this doesn't work try putting a

```
alert('test');
```

Inside the mouseup and document ready function to see if its being run at all.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It actually looks like it's not triggering... Any thoughts? I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Can you see any javascript errors? (https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors#Step_3:_Diagnosis)

I suspect an error might be stopping your script from running at all. Try putting an alert at the top of your javascript file.

Comment: Sorted it out... don't know why, but when I just removed `'.main-navigation.toggled'` it did the trick.